# Laravel Custom CommandBus not found

Tags: php, laravel

I created a custom APIController to extend generic controller.
The custom API Controller is this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API\v1;

use App\Commanding\CommandBus;
use App\Commanding\ValidationCommandBus;

use League\Fractal\Manager;
use League\Fractal\Resource\Collection;
use League\Fractal\Resource\Item;

use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Http\Response as IlluminateResponse;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller as BaseController;

class APIController extends BaseController {

    protected $statusCode = 200;

    // Fractal API Manager
    protected $fractal;

    public function __construct(ValidationCommandBus $commandBus, Manager $fractal) {
        // Init fractal manager
        $this->fractal = $fractal;
        $this->commandBus = $commandBus;
    }

    // Get the current status code
    public function getStatusCode() {
        return $this->statusCode;
    }

    // Set the current status code
    public function setStatusCode($statusCode) {
        $this->statusCode = $statusCode;
        return $this;
    }

    // Respond with data and set status code
    public function respond($data, $headers = []) {
        return response()->json($data, $this->getStatusCode(), $headers, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }

    protected function respondWithItem($item, $callback) {
        $resource = new Item($item, $callback);
        $rootScope = $this->fractal->createData($resource);
        return $rootScope->toArray();
    }

    protected function respondWithCollection($collection, $callback) {
        $resource = new Collection($collection, $callback);
        $rootScope = $this->fractal->createData($resource);
        return $rootScope->toArray();
    }

    protected function respondWithCollectionAndResourceKey($collection, $resourceKey, $callback) {
        $resource = new Collection($collection, $callback, $resourceKey);
        $rootScope = $this->fractal->createData($resource);
        return $rootScope->toArray();
    }

    protected function respondWithPagination($paginationData, $data) {
        $response = array_merge($data, $pagination = [
            'pagination' => [
                'total' => $paginationData->total(),
                'perPage' => $paginationData->perPage(),
                'lastPage' => $paginationData->lastPage(),
                'nextPageUrl' => $paginationData->nextPageUrl(),
                'prevPageUrl' => $paginationData->previousPageUrl(),
                'from' => $paginationData->firstItem(),
                'to' => $paginationData->lastItem(),
                'totalPages' => ceil($paginationData->total() / $paginationData->perPage()),
                'currentPage' => $paginationData->currentPage(),
                'hasMorePages' => $paginationData->hasMorePages()
            ]
        ]);

        return $this->respond($response);
    }

    // Respond with error
    public function respondWithError($message) {
        return $this->respond([
            'error' => [
                'message' => $message,
                'status_code' => $this->getStatusCode()
            ]
        ]);
    }

    // Delete
    public function respondWithSuccessfulDeletion($message) {
        return $this->setStatusCode(200)->respond([
            'message' => $message
        ]);
    }

    // Response Validation Failed
    public function respondValidationFailed($message) {
        return $this->setStatusCode(422)->respondWithError($message);
    }

    // Response Internal Error
    public function respondWithInternalError($message) {
        return $this->setStatusCode(500)->respond([
            'message' => $message,
            'status_code' => $this->getStatusCode()
        ]);
    }
}
```

This controller has a property called `commandBus` which I would like to access by extending another controller with this APIController.

```
class APIMFUserController extends APIController {...}
```

In PHPStorm I get the error, when I call `$this->commandBus->execute` that the field `commandBus` has not been found and it seems the execute function does not get called. How do I fix this?

Comment: is `APIMFUserController` contains `commandBus` var ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the property `protected $commandBus;` to your class:

```
class APIController extends BaseController {

    protected $statusCode = 200;

    // Fractal API Manager
    protected $fractal;

    protected $commandBus;

    public function __construct(ValidationCommandBus $commandBus, Manager $fractal) {
        // Init fractal manager
        $this->fractal = $fractal;
        $this->commandBus = $commandBus;
    }
```